# Table Rows Disappear on Dropdown ItemSelected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Every time I change a dropdown on a webpage, the page "resets". A row I've inserted programmatically disappears and a new one is written. I want to let the user add multiple rows.

I'm attempting to

1. Use a dropdown to fill mulitple GridViews displaying product infromation
2. User will add a quantity in a text box
3. Click 'Add to cart', which will...
4. Create a new row on an *existing* Table on that page with the selected product details

This works fine for the first row only, however, if I change the dropdown or click the 'Add to cart' button, the newly inserted row will be overwritten by the row from subsequent updates.

This is my table...

```
<asp:Table ID="tblOrderPreview" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Width="800px" >
    <asp:TableHeaderRow BorderStyle= "Solid"><asp:TableHeaderCell>Product</asp:TableHeaderCell><asp:TableHeaderCell>Qty</asp:TableHeaderCell><asp:TableHeaderCell>Price</asp:TableHeaderCell><asp:TableHeaderCell>Total</asp:TableHeaderCell><asp:TableCell><b>Remove Item</b></asp:TableCell></asp:TableHeaderRow>
    <asp:TableRow BorderStyle= "Solid"><asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

And this is the code the button calls:

```
Protected Sub btnAddToCart_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddToCart.Click
    lblValidator.Visible = False


        If txtQuantity.Text <> "" Then

            lblValidator.Visible = False

        Dim name As String
        name = GridView3.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text.ToString

        Dim qantity As Integer
        qantity = Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity.Text)

        Dim price As String
        price = Convert.ToDouble(GridView5.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text.ToString)

        Dim total As String
        total = "$" + (price * qantity).ToString

        'insert new row to tblOrderPreview (count rows, then insert another row named COUNT+1
        Dim tRow As New TableRow()
        tblOrderPreview.Rows.Add(tRow)

        Dim tCellProduct As New TableCell()
        tCellProduct.Text = name
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellProduct)

        Dim tCellQty As New TableCell()
        tCellQty.Text = qantity.ToString
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellQty)

        Dim tCellPrice As New TableCell()
        tCellPrice.Text = price
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellPrice)

        Dim tCellTotal As New TableCell()
        tCellTotal.Text = total
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellTotal)

        Dim tCellRemove As New TableCell()
        tCellRemove.Text = "del!"
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCellRemove)


    Else
        lblValidator.Visible = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried getting each row, within `tblOrderPreview` at the start of this function as a `TableRowCollection`, at the end re-adding the `TableRowCollection` and then adding your new row?

Comment: @FirstCape useful thanks. I've done  some reading and this could be the thing

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify my comment above and show some code:

```
Dim tblRowColl As TableRowCollection = tblOrderPreview.Rows

'Run the code that gets the new row

For Each tblRow As TableRow In tblRowColl
    tblOrderPreview.Rows.Add(tblRow)
Next
```

Hopefully this helps.

Thanks,

Firstcape